# React native Expo EAS build for iOS, Push notifications capability error

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, apple-push-notifications

I'm working in a managed workflow and I build my `react native` app with:

- `eas build --platform iOS`
- I use **local credentials** because I need to build and sign the package not with my Apple developer account, but for a customer. So I created with his account all needed certificates, which are the *provisioning profile* and the *distribution certificate*.
- I don't need or want to enable **Push notifications**

My `eas.json`

```
{
    "cli": {
        "version": ">= 0.47.0"
    },
    "build": {
        "production": {
            "ios": {
                "credentialsSource": "local"
            },
            "android": {
                "credentialsSource": "local"
            }
        }
    },
    "submit": {
        "production": {}
    }
}
```

The build goes fine until the *archive part*, where I get these errors:

- `error: Provisioning profile "MyAppDistributionProfile" doesn't support the Push Notifications capability. (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')`
- `error: Provisioning profile "MyAppDistributionProfile" doesn't include the aps-environment entitlement. (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')`

I really don't know what to do, also I don't understand if:

1. Do I need to write somewhere in the expo config file that I don't want Push notification?
2. Do I need to change something in my distribution profile, maybe generate it with some different flags? Maybe with expo build to enable the Push notifications is mandatory?

My profile `entitlements` (**no one**!):

[image]